# Google Map API - setPanel - Cannot read property 'text' of undefined

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been trying this transit example. This is not the ZERO_RESULTS error. 
When I am using direction API with TRANSIT mode. For specific locations, I do get a route, however there is an uncaught typeerror for SetPanel. I have attached one such example. This works well with most locations. However, for the route I have entered in the example, I do receive such errors. There are many such routes which result in this error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined

http://jsfiddle.net/zfz477e8/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Transit</title>
    <script
      src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        color: black;
        font-family: arial,sans-serif;
        font-size: 13px;
      }

      #map {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 50%;
      }

      #panel-wpr {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 50%;
        right: 0;
        overflow: auto;
      }

      #panel {
        font-family: arial;
        padding: 0 5px;
      }

      #info {
        padding: 5px;
      }

      #from {
        width: 90%;
        font-size: 1.2em;
      }

      .adp-directions {
        width: 100%;
      }

      .input {
        background-color: white;
        padding-left: 8px;
        border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
        border-top: 1px solid silver;
        -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
        -moz-border-radius: 1px;
        border-radius: 1px;
      }

      .time {
        margin: 0;
        height: 17px;
        border: 1px solid;
        border-top-color: #CCC;
        border-right-color: #999;
        border-left-color: #999;
        border-bottom-color: #CCC;
        padding: 2px 15px 1px 1px;
      }

      button {
        border: 1px solid #3079ED;
        color: white;
        background-color: #4D90FE;
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#4D90FE),to(#4787ED));
          background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#4D90FE,#4787ED);
          background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4D90FE,#4787ED);
          background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#4D90FE,#4787ED);
          background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#4D90FE,#4787ED);
          background-image: linear-gradient(top,#4D90FE, #4787ED);
          filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#4d90fe',EndColorStr='#4787ed');
          display: inline-block;
          min-width: 54px;
          text-align: center;
          font-weight: bold;
          padding: 0 8px;
          line-height: 27px;
          -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
          -moz-border-radius: 2px;
          border-radius: 2px;
          -webkit-transition: all 0.218s;
          -moz-transition: all 0.218s;
          -o-transition: all 0.218s;
          transition: all 0.218s;
          }

        #info div {
          line-height: 22px;
          font-size: 110%;
          }

        .btn {
        }

        #panel-wpr {
          border-left: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
        }

        #info {
          border-bottom: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
          margin-bottom: 5px;
        }

        h2 {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
        }

    </style>

    <script>
      var directions = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
      var renderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
      var map, transitLayer;

      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 13,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.7482333, -73.8681295),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('go'), 'click',
        route);

        var input = document.getElementById('from');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

        transitLayer = new google.maps.TransitLayer();

        var control = document.getElementById('transit-wpr');
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(control);

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(control, 'click', function() {
          transitLayer.setMap(transitLayer.getMap() ? null : map);
        });

        addDepart();
        route();
      }

      function addDepart() {
        var depart = document.getElementById('depart');
        for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
          for (var j = 0; j < 60; j += 15) {
          var x = i < 10 ? '0' + i : i;
          var y = j < 10 ? '0' + j : j;
          depart.innerHTML += '<option>' + x + ':' + y + '</option>';
        }
        }
      }

      function route() {
        var departure = document.getElementById('depart').value;
        var bits = departure.split(':');
        var now = new Date();
        var tzOffset = (now.getTimezoneOffset() + 60) * 60 * 1000;

        var time = new Date();
        time.setHours(bits[0]);
        time.setMinutes(bits[1]);

        var ms = time.getTime() - tzOffset;
        if (ms < now.getTime()) {
          ms += 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        }

        var departureTime = new Date(ms);

        var request = {
          origin: document.getElementById('from').value,
          destination: '51 St, New York, NY 10022, USA',
          travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.TRANSIT,
          provideRouteAlternatives: true,
          transitOptions: {
            departureTime: departureTime
          }
        };

        var panel = document.getElementById('panel');
        panel.innerHTML = '';
        directions.route(request, function(response, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            renderer.setDirections(response);
            renderer.setMap(map);
            renderer.setPanel(panel);
            console.log(renderer.getDirections());
          } else {
            renderer.setMap(null);
            renderer.setPanel(null);
          }
       
        });

      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="transit-wpr">
      <button id="transit">Toggle transit layer</button>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="panel-wpr">
      <div id="info">
        <div>
          <h2>Transit directions</h2>
        </div>
        <div> 
          <label>from:</label>
          <input class="input" id="from" value="Grand Central 42, NY">
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>to:</label>
          <strong>51 St, New York, NY 10022, USA</strong>
        </div>
        <div>Depart at <select id="depart"></select></div>
        <div class="btn">
          <button id="go">Get Directions</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="panel"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The issue appears to be with directions.js. It appears departure_time object is undefined for routes where error is raised

Comment: I think the issue is where api lists 4 options and one of which is WALK only. There is no departure / arrival time available for WALK only mode hence this error. but latter is not handled

Comment: I did something like this with local instance of directions.js and it appears to work fine. g.j[2]=(h.arrival_time ===undefined)?h.arrival_time:h.arrival_time.text; (same changes with departure_time) But how do I fix this to app working? Alternatively is there any option by which I can direct API not to display WALK only options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug in the [release and experimental versions of the API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions)

```
(experimental) v=3.exp or no version string     has the error
(release)      v=3                              has the error
???            v=3.22                           doesn't have the error 
(frozen)       v=3.0 or v=3.21                  doesn't have the error
```

Issue in the issue tracker: [Issue 9307: Google Map API - setPanel - Cannot read property 'text' of undefined](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9307)

- [fiddle v=3.21](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/zfz477e8/11/)
- [fiddle v=3.22](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/zfz477e8/12/)
- [fiddle v=3.23](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/zfz477e8/13/)
- [fiddle v=3](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/zfz477e8/14/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var directions = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var renderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var map, transitLayer;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.7482333, -73.8681295),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('go'), 'click',
    route);

  var input = document.getElementById('from');
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

  transitLayer = new google.maps.TransitLayer();

  var control = document.getElementById('transit-wpr');
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(control);

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(control, 'click', function() {
    transitLayer.setMap(transitLayer.getMap() ? null : map);
  });

  addDepart();
  route();
}

function addDepart() {
  var depart = document.getElementById('depart');
  for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 60; j += 15) {
      var x = i < 10 ? '0' + i : i;
      var y = j < 10 ? '0' + j : j;
      depart.innerHTML += '<option>' + x + ':' + y + '</option>';
    }
  }
}

function route() {
  var departure = document.getElementById('depart').value;
  var bits = departure.split(':');
  var now = new Date();
  var tzOffset = (now.getTimezoneOffset() + 60) * 60 * 1000;

  var time = new Date();
  time.setHours(bits[0]);
  time.setMinutes(bits[1]);

  var ms = time.getTime() - tzOffset;
  if (ms < now.getTime()) {
    ms += 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  }

  var departureTime = new Date(ms);

  var request = {
    origin: document.getElementById('from').value,
    destination: '51 St, New York, NY 10022, USA',
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.TRANSIT,
    provideRouteAlternatives: true,
    transitOptions: {
      departureTime: departureTime
    }
  };

  var panel = document.getElementById('panel');
  panel.innerHTML = '';
  directions.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      renderer.setDirections(response);
      renderer.setMap(map);
      renderer.setPanel(panel);
      console.log(renderer.getDirections());
    } else {
      renderer.setMap(null);
      renderer.setPanel(null);
    }

  });

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: black;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}
#map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 50%;
}
#panel-wpr {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
#panel {
  font-family: arial;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
#info {
  padding: 5px;
}
#from {
  width: 90%;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.adp-directions {
  width: 100%;
}
.input {
  background-color: white;
  padding-left: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
  border-top: 1px solid silver;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
  -moz-border-radius: 1px;
  border-radius: 1px;
}
.time {
  margin: 0;
  height: 17px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-top-color: #CCC;
  border-right-color: #999;
  border-left-color: #999;
  border-bottom-color: #CCC;
  padding: 2px 15px 1px 1px;
}
button {
  border: 1px solid #3079ED;
  color: white;
  background-color: #4D90FE;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#4D90FE), to(#4787ED));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4D90FE, #4787ED);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4D90FE, #4787ED);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4D90FE, #4787ED);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4D90FE, #4787ED);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #4D90FE, #4787ED);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#4d90fe', EndColorStr='#4787ed');
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 54px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 8px;
  line-height: 27px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.218s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.218s;
  -o-transition: all 0.218s;
  transition: all 0.218s;
}
#info div {
  line-height: 22px;
  font-size: 110%;
}
.btn {} #panel-wpr {
  border-left: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}
#info {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.21&libraries=places"></script>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Transit</title>
<div id="transit-wpr">
  <button id="transit">Toggle transit layer</button>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="panel-wpr">
  <div id="info">
    <div>
      <h2>Transit directions</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>from:</label>
      <input class="input" id="from" value="Grand Central 42, NY">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>to:</label>
      <strong>51 St, New York, NY 10022, USA</strong>
    </div>
    <div>Depart at
      <select id="depart"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
      <button id="go">Get Directions</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="panel"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: isnt v3.22 release? as per the documentation it says 3.22 against release. so issue is with experimental only?

Comment: from the docs - The current release version is 3.22. You can request it with either of the following bootstraps:

Comment: It wasn't consistent when I tested it, I think v=3.22 was just moved to release.